# How to Connect two LANs?

Tags: networking, lan, vlan

I have the following LANs:

**LAN A**
IP Range: 192.168.1.x
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

In LAN A using a NetGear Router (Model WGR614v9) I am connected with WAN. Router B (TP-Link TL-WR741N) is connected with Router A using LAN port.

In Router B I have following Settings to connect to WAN using Router A on LAN A:

IP Address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS Server: 192.168.1.1 , 0.0.0.0

So its connected with WAN using Router A. LAN B is configured on Router B as follows:

**LAN B**
IP Range: 192.160.1.x
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
Default Gateway: 192.160.1.1

Router A has a static Route to Router B which is as follows:
Destination: 192.160.1.0
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
Gateway: 192.168.1.2 (which is Router B)
Metrix: 2

These two LANs are used for two different departments of the Company. Each LAN has its own Server configured. So we did not want to change subnet of any LAN.

LAN B is using Internet using LAN A nicely. I can ping any PC in LAN A from LAN B. BUT **My problem is** I Can't ping any PC in LAN B from LAN A. Also No PC see other Network PCs in Network Section (Windows 7 and 8)...

Please help me how to make these two networks talkative with each other...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are facing is caused by the router on LAN B. It performs NAT, which you don't want in this setup. All traffic from LAN B to LAN A within LAN A has the source address of the router in LAN B. You want a router that only forwards traffic between networks, not translation.

Check the manual for your router to see if you can disable NAT. If not, try to find a router which doesn't have NAT. Most SMB and branch routers have this functionality, you could pick up an out-date model on eBay for USD 50-100. Alternatively as a workaround you could set up port-forwarding (there are many good guides online).